# Android Studio, AndroidX, "Cannot resolve method.." on ViewModelProviders.of(this)

Tags: android, viewmodel, androidx, android-viewmodel

As I can see this is pretty common misunderstanding. I am currently following one online guide, so I can get into the things in android studio. So the problem is that on `cotactViewModel = ViewModel.Providers.of(this).get(ContactViewModel.class);`, on `this` it notes `Cannot resolve method of(this)`. I browse the web, if the activity is a Fragment/ViewModel activity, it actually works, but the guy on the guide does it using `Empty Activity`.

Thanks!

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.courseproject_pmiu">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.courseproject_pmiu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ContactViewModel contactViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContactViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.courseproject_pmiu"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0-rc01"
    def room_version = "2.0.0-rc01"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [androidX lifecycle libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies) but you're not [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to androidX.

**If** you want to migrate to androidX then remove support libs and use AndroidX libs.

To solve this import androidX instead of support.

**Use:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

**instead of:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

For this you have to remove all support libraries from your build.gradle app level and add androidX appCompact.

After modify your build.gradle look like this.

```
dependencies {
def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0-rc01"
def room_version = "2.0.0-rc01"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

**Important:**

And at last check your gradle.properties these below properties are there if not add them:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**Else**

**Not recomended**

If you prefer to use support libraries then import these [pre-androidX libs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#pre-androidx_dependencies) for lifecycle.

Comment: Awesome, I just notice that I've messed up the lifecycle annotationProcessor too.. The "migration" things is one of the many things I've did wrong (or didn't do at all), 
Seems like one video explaining every letter is just not enough for me. Everything works now, Thanks for the time spend!

Comment: Oh I missed to add that in the dependencies at the `lifecycle compiler` it should be 
 `annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"`